# ListView with 3 columns - Android

Tags: android, android-listview, baseadapter

I want to create `ListView` with 3 columns (all 3 columns will be the same). So one column is one `ImageView`. For populating the `ListView` I have an array with images.

Design should be like this:
[image: Layout]

To populate ListView I need custom Adapter and custom Layout. Layout is only 3 images with id-s:
`ivImage1`, `ivImage2`, `ivImage3`

My custom adapter:

```
public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private int[] gallery = {
            R.drawable.cat_321_sofa,
            R.drawable.cat_corner_sofa,
            R.drawable.cat_beds,
            R.drawable.cat_arm_chairs,
            R.drawable.cat_puff,
            R.drawable.cat_coffe_table,
            R.drawable.cat_day_night,
    };

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.one_gallery_layout, parent, false);
        } else {
            row = convertView;
        }

        ImageView ivImage1 = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.ivImage1);
        ImageView ivImage2 = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.ivImage2);
        ImageView ivImage3 = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.ivImage3);

        ivImage1.setImageResource(); ??????
        ivImage2.setImageResource(); ??????
        ivImage3.setImageResource(); ??????

        return row;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return ????????????
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

So the problem is the size of `ListView`, the return of getCount(); , and putting image on every `ImageView`

How can I do this, or there is some other solution for this problem.....

Comment: could this be a GridView instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use either [GridView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html), or [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html).  Both of these components will allow you to create multiple columns, which is what you need.  I would suggest going with RecyclerView which is the supported control for this going forward.

Standard ListView is limited to a single column.

Comment: Thanks, Ill try to use GridView or RecyclerView :)